# Where is Perforce workspace mapping stored?

Tags: perforce

Where does Perforce store workspace mapping configuration (in P4V accessible through Menu > Connections > Edit Current Workspace... > tab Basic, [related P4V guide](https://www.perforce.com/perforce/r17.2/manuals/p4v/using.workspaces.html))?

Example of workspace mapping:

```
//depot/...         //bruno/depot/...
//user_depot/...    //bruno/user_depot/...
//projects/...      //bruno/myprojects/...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All of the metadata for each workspace (and everything else) is stored in the server database.  (Client views specifically live in the `db.view` table.)

Comment: Thank you. Could you please share location of the `db.view` file?

Comment: If you need to ask where the backend database is stored, you shouldn't be trying to mess with it.  :)  Use the `p4 client` end-user command to actually edit the client view.